# Is this a good way to hard code permissions in frontend?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, user-permissions

I am building an inventory management application, where admin user can also change the permissions of other employees. Some of the permissions depend on other permissions to operate. And i have to display some other name on front-end for a particular permission, and there is some differences at the back-end: for user ease ability.

Currently i am just passing out the hard coded values in the function to make changes to permissions.

Here is an example:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="h-4 w-4 text-blue-600 bg-blue-600" (change)="extractPermissions(permission, ['view stock_company', 'add stock_company', 'edit stock_company', 'delete stock_company'])" #permission>
```

I am wandering if this is a good approach of hard coding all the permissions in HTML/JS, because i have more than 250 permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using json structure to store all permissions once and call them whenever you need it.

```
json = '["view stock_company", "add stock_company", "edit stock_company", "delete stock_company"]' ; 

parsedJson  = JSON.parse( json ) 
console.log( parsedJson )
```

Comment: Okay!, thats good, but after that, do i need to implement permissions in hard coded way? Because i am fetching permissions from API. But it makes me confused that do i need to implement each permission separately (in the required form). Is this a good way?

Comment: What I would do is to create some kind of user groups to limit the number 250 to 5 or 6 different categories. And also we do not have to support user privileges from input. We can just create a hash for each user. When we are provided the hash we check whether user signed in properly. [ cookies etc.] When we need to decide if the user has access to certain priviledges we can just check its username or hash and if it matches this certain groups. As a security concern What I would suppose is everybody can see frontend therefore we should minimize the risk by handling as much amap in backend.

Comment: By the way, just for this reason to hide the permissions from front-end i am maping permissions back-end:front-end.... Like if the user has permission ''add_with_suppervision stock'' at backend then i will be maping it as  ''add_with_suppervision stock'': "Add stock" And added a flag that consider it as Required for supervision.

Comment: By the way you clicked me, i have created a maping of backend and front-end permissions to hide them from front-end. And then handled the permissions with the help of those maping when returned back from the client for update.